# How to freely click between to open forms. VBA

Tags: forms, excel, vba

I've been searching for a bit but not seeming to be hitting the right keywords.

What I am hoping to achieve is to have 2 separate user forms visible side by side. Both forms will have their own functionality and purpose but are meant to be used in conjunction with each other at times (hence the side by side). I would like to be able to click back and forth between the two forms freely, preferably with just a mouse click, like one would with their open applications on their desktop or OS.

I can't seem to even find ways or methods to make make the unfocused form active.

I am not a super strong programmer but I wouldn't consider myself a noob, but there are still a lot of syntax I've been seeing that looks greek to me and don't understand.

working on Microsoft Office Excel for Mac 2011

Thanks for any help guys and gals.

Cheers

Comment: Maybe you can post what you tried by far?

Comment: This is a very broad question and it would help to see what you have done so far. Is the code for each form on a separate workbook or are they both on the same? If they are on the same, you might want to consider integrating both into one form with separate pages or tabs instead of having two forms. If you insist on two forms on the same workbook however, you should start by looking at the initialize events for each form and determine whether you want the second form to be launched from the first while the first is active, or what other event is suitable depending on what you are looking for.

Comment: I understand that it was kind of a broad question, and I understand there are many ways to skin a cat, but i was kind of thinking that what I was coding on the two forms wouldn't necessarily matter on having forms unlock-able. At that time it was in concept mode and I hadn't started coding anything to be able to show you.

Comment: And Since I posted till now, I did end up changing the concept around to where having them on one form makes more sense, but I've also been pulled away from the project for awhile and possibly may be abandoning it. Thanks for posting tho.

Answer (score 3):

VBA Userforms have the property "ShowModal" setting this to False will allow the form to be selected or deselected at will, as well as multiple forms to be shown and used simultaneously (as long as they are all modeless)

This can also be accomplished in code in the show event using

```
Userform1.Show vbModeless
```

you could then use the initialize event of one form to show the second form.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
     UserForm2.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

Comment: I had like the looks for this simple coding, however I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: I googled around a little, turns out microsoft for mac doesn't support the mode. Lame

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your posts and feedback. I had been pulled away from the project for the last while, and since then have changed up the concept of it... also I may be abandoning it, but I will play around with some of the stuff you guys had advised and see what I can learn from it.

Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is a modeless dialog box. See: [how to display modal and modeless dialog boxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/39wcs2dh(v=vs.90))

### Modal Dialog Box

A modal dialog box is a dialog box that takes all user input of the application. While this dialog box is open, the other forms of the application won't respond to user input. This is the most used form of dialog boxes. Example: *the save file dialog box*. While this dialog box is open, you can't edit your document. You'll first have to close the dialog box before you can continue changing the document. You can see this in *Notepad* when you save the file. While the save file dialog box is open you can't do anything with the main form

A modal dialog box is usually shown as follows:

```
private void onButton1_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    using(var dlg = new MyModalDialog())
    {
        dlg.PropertyA = ...;  // set some properties of the dialog
        dlg.PropertyB = ...;
        var dlgResult = dlg.ShowDialog(this); // show the dialog. I am the parent

        // this procedure is blocked until the dialog is closed.
        // if here: result is available:
        switch (dlgResult)
        {
            case DialogResult.OK:
                ProcessResult(dlg.GetResult());
                break;
            case DialogResult.Cancel:
                ProcessCancel();
                break;
            default:
                 ...
        }
    }
}
```

### Modeless Dialog Box

You want a modeless dialog box: after showing one form, you want to continue in your code to be able to show the other form. For this you don't use [Form.ShowDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx) but [Form.Show](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
private MyForm1 formA = null;
private MyForm2 formB = null;
private void onButton1_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    this.formA = new MyForm1())
    this.formA.PropertyA = ...;

    this.formB = new MyForm2())
    this.formB.PropertyA = ...;

    // make sure the forms are shown side by side
    this.formA.Position = ...
    this.formA.Size = ...
    this.formB.Position = ...
    this.formB.Size = ...

    // show the forms:
    this.formA.Show(this);
    this.formB.Show(this);

    // while the form are shown, your main form can continue
    ...
}
```

You'll have to subscribe to the [Form.Closed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event before you show the forms, so you can take actions, like Disposing the forms.

```
this.FormA.Closing += new System.EventHandler(this.OnSubFormClosed);
this.FormA.Show(this);
```

In `OnSubFormClosed` you should check the 'Sender` to inspect which form is closed and act accordingly:

```
void OnSunFormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, this.formA)
    {   // FormA closed:
        this.ProcessFormAClosed();
        this.FormA.Dispose();
        this.FormA = null;
    }
    else if (Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, this.FormB)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Finally: you should inform your forms when your main form is being closed. If you do this in [Form.OnClosing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onclosing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead of [Form.OnClosed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onclosed(v=vs.110).aspx) you can ask your forms whether they are ok with it to being closed. For example, the form may ask the operator to save the file and give the opportunity to anser yes / no / cancel. In the latter case the application should not be closed. Check this behaviour if you try to close Notepad with unsaved edits.

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(cancelEventArgs e)
{
     // the following may be optimized
     bool closeFormAallowed = this.formA?.IsClosingAllowed ?? true;
     bool closeFormBallowed = this.formB?.IsClosingAllowed ?? true;

     // cancel closing if closing is not allowed
     e.Cancel = !closeFormAallowed || !closeFormBallowed;

     // don't forget to raise the event so my subscribers my decide to cancel closing:
     if (!e.cancel) base.OnClosing(e);

     // if no one wants to cancel closing: close the forms:
     if (!e.Cancel)
     {
         if (this.formA != null) this.formA.Close();
         it (this.formB != null) this.formB.Close();
         // this will raise the events, so the forms are properly disposed
     }
}
```

Comment: Your code examples use `C#`, not `Excel VBA` which OP wants

Comment: Oops! Still I hope KyeBosh understands the code and can translate it to his language. This answer might be useful for  a C# user has the same question